Given the optimal ate pairing e(A,B)=y is to possible to determine I and J such as e(I,J)=2y or even e(I,J)=3y?
Simple question : let’s say I have a pairing friendly curve having a very large trace, and that I have a pairing with points $A∈G_1$ and $B∈G_2$ such as the optimal ate pairing $e(A,B)=y$, then is it possible to fully determine 2 point $I$ and $J$ such as $e(I,J)$ equals a target multiple of the finite’s field element $y$ ?
Or does it requires full pairing or full Miller’s inversion and thus would be impossible on a curve like bn254 ?

In cases of cryptographic interest, no such solutions exist.
Recall that cryptographic elliptic curve pairings take values in a multiplicative subgroup of prime order $\ell$ in an extension field $\mathbb F_p^n$ where $n$ is the smallest value such that $\ell|p^n-1$. In particular then there $\ell\not | p-1$ and there are no non-trivial roots of unity in $\mathbb F_p$.
Given $y$ as a possible pairing output from two points $A$ and $B$ we can deduce that $y$ is an $\ell$th root of unity. Exhibiting $2y$ as a pairing output allows us to deduce that $2y$ is also an $\ell$th root of unity and hence that 2 is also an $\ell$th root of unity. This contradicts the paragraph above. The same argument holds for any element of $\mathbb F_p$.
If $\alpha$ is an $\ell$th root of unity in $\mathbb F_p^n$, then there do exist $I$ and $J$ with $e(I,J)=\alpha y$, though finding such with $\alpha$ independent of $A$, $B$ and $y$ will be as hard as targetted pairing
